# AsyncTask is not working

Tags: android, class, android-activity, android-asynctask

I have splash activity that should download data from the url parse it and pass it to main activity , while downloading i created layout with logo and spining gif loaded in webview ,but when i start app nothing happend ,it wont start main activity here is the code

```
public class Init extends Activity {

static final String DEFAULT_URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.init);

    WebView loader = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.loader);
    loader.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

    new LoadingTask().execute(DEFAULT_URL);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public class LoadingTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String URL = params[0];
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
         // getting DOM element
        return xml;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        Intent startApp = new Intent("com.example.androidhive.HOME");
        startApp.putExtra("xmlstring", result);
        //finish();
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
startactivity(startApp);
```

in post execute to go to next activity

Answer (score 1):

you missed line,

```
startactivity(startApp);
```

something like,

```
Intent startApp = new Intent("com.example.androidhive.HOME");
startApp.putExtra("xmlstring", result);
startactivity(startApp);
```